# Removing reference passing in PHP method

Tags: php, reference

I would like to remove the pass by reference(s) in this method, how would I do this?

```
    public function insertFirst($data)
    {
        $link = New Node($data);
        $link->next = $this->first;
        $this->first =& $link;

        if(null === $this->last)
            $this->last = &$link;

        $this->count++;

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Why would you delete the reference? That would ruin the code, as you only save duplicates

Comment: Just remove the ampersands, they're not accomplishing anything since objects are references in PHP. E.g. `$link = new Node($data); $link2 = $link;` both `$link` and `$link2` refer to the same object instance.  Have a try.

Comment: BTW, I can't speak for the user, but my guess as to why your question received a downvote would be because it does not demonstrate your research effort and/or what you had tried on your own before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Node()` will give you a reference - no need for `=&` here.

/edit: if already at "micro-opts", `++$var` is a little bit faster than `$var++` ;)